# Is there a better way of writing differentiation and integration?

Tags: integration, derivatives, notation

Differentiation is commonly written simply with a prime mark and an equation, as $(x^2)' = 2x$. Although I find this confusing and think it'd better be written $D(x\mapsto x^2) = x\mapsto 2x$, as $x^2$ itself isn't a function. But this notation doesn't allow for specific values, so I was wondering if there was a common way of writing it?

Would this be acceptable: $D(x\mapsto x^2)|_{x=a} = 2a$?

And how would one write integration in similar terms? $I(x\mapsto x^2) = x\mapsto \frac{1}{3}x^3+C$ ? And how would one write definite integration? $I(x\mapsto x^2)_{x_1=a}^{x_2=b} = \frac{1}{3}b^3-\frac{1}{3}a^3$?

Edit: What I'd like to know is if there is a more rigorous notation for differentiation and integration that doesn't hide the fact that you're dealing with functions and not equations. Simple and shortened notation is useful when doing calculations, but not for getting an understanding of what you're doing. I want a better understanding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Neither is $x\mapsto x^2$ a function, since you haven't told us the domain. Completeness in notation can be the death of clarity.

Comment: How would you write the differential equation $y''=y'$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Lets say it's $\mathbb{R}$ the the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews can I borrow your last phrase (for signatures on forum posts, etc)?

Comment: My point wasn't to ask a question, but to point out that you still haven't defined a function, even though you seem to think $x\mapsto x^2$ is somehow more a function definition than just writing $x^2$. The fact that you have to step out and say $\mathbb R$ separate from the notation *is* my point.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Sure. :)

Comment: @JuliánAguirre $D^2(x\mapsto y) = D(x\mapsto y)$?

Comment: That notation for the differential equation does not make clear at all what you are trying to solve for, to me. @fvel

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I just want to know if there is a less ambiguous way than $(x^2)'$ as I feel this is more easily misunderstood. And the difference between $g(f)(x)$ and $g(f(x))$ is often not taught which really misses the importance of distinction.

Comment: Well, there's $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)$, the other common notation. @fvel

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If you think $D^2(x\mapsto y) = D(x\mapsto y)$ is unclear, it is because it is. My point is that I ask if there is an unambiguous way of writing differentiation which explains the process in a nice way, instead of magically changing symbols without knowing what the meaning of it all is. $y'' = y'$ is very convenient to use when you know the reasoning behind those symbols, but they mystify what you're actually doing. The problem I is that if you teach $y'' =y'$ without going through $D^2(x\mapsto y) = D(x\mapsto y), x\in \mathbb{R}$ first you don't get as good understanding.

Comment: There is the Newton style $y'$ and the Leibniz style $ \frac{d f}{dx}$ for derivatives. Leibniz notation was essential for the propagation of calculus in the 18th century.

Comment: There is the notation $D_xx^2 = 2x, \left.{D_xx^2}\right\vert_{x = a} = 2a$, if you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

You could say $D(x\mapsto x^2)(a) = 2a$.  It's incorrect to say that is $a \to 2a$, because evaluation of the function $D(x \mapsto x^2) = x \mapsto 2x$ at $x=a$ should give a number, not a function.

Comment: I fixed the $\mapsto$-part of my question. This answer does not fully answer my question about integration.

Answer (score 0):

When the dash notation is employed, the respective variable is usually implicit from the context -- typically it's $x$, or the first argument of a function.   So we generally know what $y', {(x^2+h(x))}', f'(x), g'(u)$ all mean.

If confusion can arise, you can always make the respective variable explicit by placing it in a subscript.  $${\big(x^2+f\circ g(x)+y\big)}'_x = 2x + g(x)\cdot f'\circ g(x)+y'_x$$

Another way to express a derivative is to use the linear operator, $\mathcal D_x\;$, to mean $\frac{\mathrm d\;}{\mathrm d x}$.

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{\mathrm d\;}{\mathrm d x} x^2 & = \mathcal D_x \,x^2 \\ & = {(x^2)}'_x \\ & = 2x 
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{\mathrm d\;}{\mathrm d x} f(x) & = \mathcal D_x \,f(x) \\ & = f'(x)  
\end{align}$$